# Why Does Intellisense Offer Json for a Constant?

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

I declared a constant, assigned to a `fetch`. Now, intellisense offers `json` for that constant.

Is it because vscode knows that fetch can return json?

```
import {topHeadlinesURL} from 'newsAPI.js';

// Delay execution until page loads
window.addEventListener('load', ()=> {
    kvetchNews();
});

async function kvetchNews(){
    const res = await fetch(topHeadlinesURL);
    const json = await res.json();
}
```

[image]

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. The ability to invoke `.json` on a variable isn't determined by how you declare that variable, `var` or `let` or `const`. It's determined by the value stored therein.

Comment: @meagar plz unhold the question, i've added a picture for clarity.

Comment: The picture doesn't add any clarity. It's not clear why you think "constant" is relevant here; as already pointed out, `fetch` returns something that has a `.json` method on it, and VSCode knows this because `fetch` is a built-in standard function; it returns a promise, which you're `await`ing, so the resolved value will be a `Response` object that has a `.json` method.

Comment: @meagar because "res" is the name of the constant on which intellisense is offering json. Let me know what's unclear about that. Why is it necessary to hold the question in order to discuss it?

Comment: @meagar Is your comment the answer? In that case, plz unhold the question and post your answer properly as an answer. Thx

Comment: Ahh, so you want to know why IntelliSense would know that `const res` would have a `.json` method, and has nothing to do with `const json` as such

Comment: Because there's no useful answer to give here. Intellisense offers `.json` because it knows `.json` is something you can invoke on the value stored in `res`, and its job is to suggest these things to save you time and keystrokes.

Comment: @meagar how does it know that?

Comment: Because [fetch is a standard that is well defined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Comment: how is that not a useful answer?

Comment: @meagar you have not explained the problem with my question. Jaromanda understands what i'm asking. You obviously understand the question, because you answered. Please unhold the question, and post your answer as an answer.

Comment: I guess one reason that this question is on hold is because the answer can be considered to not be useful. You believe it is, but sadly those who voted to put the question on hold did not.

Comment: @evolutionbox, now that we have an answer, what about that answer isn't useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things; first:

> Why Does Intellisense Offer Json for a Constant?

That the variable is a `const` isn't relevant to the methods the VSCode will suggest. The type of variable doesn't determine what methods can be invoked on it, the *value* of the variable does. Your variable could be declared `var`, `let` or `const` and it wouldn't change the suggestion of `.json`.

Second:

> Is it because vscode knows that fetch can return json?

This demonstrates a misunderstanding of what VSCode is offering you. Whether or not a method returns JSON is irrelevant (`fetch` does not), VSCode is suggesting the method `json` because it knows that the object held by the variable has a `json` method.

In this case, `fetch` returns a promise, which resolves to a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object that has implements the [`Body` mixin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body), which provides a [`json` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json). You're `await`ing that promise, so the value stored in the variable with be that response object, on which you can invoke `json`.

VSCode knows this, because `fetch` is part of a standard and well documented API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

All VSCode is doing is offering you suggestions for which methods are available for you, saving you the effort of remembering the exact method names and typing them out. Not much of a savings for the four letter `json` method, but it can be useful for longer methods or for objects that have many methods.